# Appropriate use of through association

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, associations, sequelize.js

## Currently using:

Sequelize, Postgres, Nodejs

## Situation:

I have a `User` model with some personal details (`firstName`, `lastName`, `dateOfBirth`,...)
The `User` model has several `hasOne` associations with other models (`UserAddress`,`UserContact`,...), which in turn have a `belongsTo` association to the respective `User`. Checking the tables show that these other models have a `UserUuid` column.

**In my front-end, I want to be able to notify the user at a glance how much info they have filled out for for address, phone contact etc.**

I created a `UserDetail` model, which contains a column for each of the tables for further details, accepting an `ENUM` with options `empty`,`incomplete`,`complete`. `UserDetail` has `hasOne` associations with these models, which also have a `belongsTo` association in return.
Also, `User` `hasOne` `UserDetail` & `UserDetail` `belongsTo` `User`.

**Is this the most efficient set up?**

I'm wondering if this could use a `through` association because any table such as `UserAddress` has a `UserUuid` column, as well as a `UserDetailId` column. However, the sequelize docs seem to only use `through` associations when there is a `belongsToMany` or `hasMany` relationship, where as this involves 1:1 only.

Comment: i don't understand, if user only hasone `useraddress` and etc , why make them models and not just attributes like firstName? and I don't see the use `userdetail` model either. seems just making things more and more complicated.  if you want to show the user if their info is incomplete why not just check if its null or against default value ? and I definitely don't see the use of `through`

Comment: Because some users will have restricted access. I want to limit access to certain tables depending on the users' permission levels.

The purpose of the userdetail model is to receive information at a glance about the completion statuses for every table without having to request rows from each table and checking the values in them.